# Rails instance variable spits out SQL code instead of length

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a weird one here and it only happens under development mode. This line (in the controller):

```
@searches.length
```

Produces this error:

> NoMethodError: undefined method `fields' for nil:NilClass: SELECT searches.*, COUNT(searchTerm) AS timesSearched FROM`searches`  WHERE (results = 0 AND searchDate > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)) GROUP BY searchTerm ORDER BY timesSearched DESC, searchDate DESC

That SQL is the query that gets called and then assigned to this instance variable. This doesn't happen in production mode and it didn't use to happen.

I'm thinking it must be something with my development environment but can't think of what it could possibly be.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Ruby 1.8.7 and Rails 3.1.1

**Edit:** posting development environment file contents

```
  config.cache_classes = false
  config.whiny_nils = true
  config.encoding = "utf-8"
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false
  config.active_support.deprecation = :log
  config.action_dispatch.best_standards_support = :builtin
  config.assets.compress = false
  config.assets.debug = false
  config.assets.precompile += %w( *.css )
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that the database you have configured under development doesn't have the table/fields required for the search (hence trying to .length on a NULL). It can be something as small as a field having its allow null flag changed.

Also have any permissions changed on your development database (change in password, allowed hosts etc)?

Otherwise create a dump of your production database, use that to create a temporary database and point your development config at that database and see if you get the same error.

Also compare your production and development configuration files.

If you have any more info post on here and we'll see if we can help :)

Dave

Comment: Thanks. Production and development databases are the same one. Production and development files are quite different, they need to be right? Though I can't see any options that might be causing a problem in the dev file. Any other ideas?

Comment: Default configs usually have a few lines different. How different depends on the complexity of the project. 
Also I notice you have config.whiny_nils set to true. By default production has this set to false, development has it set to true. Basically this will cause an error when methods act on nil objects.
You could try @searches.length unless @searches.nil?

Comment: I did try setting whiny_nils off and same error, which makes sense because it's complaining about an undefined method. With unless @searches.nil? I get the same error :(

Comment: Can you post the code that populates @searches? 
I just noticed "FROM searches`" Can you spot the extra apostrophe, this would cause the MySQL error.

Comment: It's not apostrophe, it's a backtick that is actually balanced, it's just this page's rendering that doesn't include it. The backtick is in fact added by the Rails interpreter since I have this `select("searches.*, COUNT(searchTerm) AS timesSearched").where("results = 0 AND searchDate > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)" ).group("searchTerm").reorder("timesSearched DESC, searchDate DESC")`

Comment: Keep the ideas coming though cause I'm stumped :) I appreciate the help.

Comment: No problem, this is an interesting error for sure. Are both development and production using identical versions of any Gems you are using? Sounds daft but it's caught me out a few times, to the point of specifying Gem versions in the Gemfile and manually upgrading!

Comment: How could a different gem be used for Production than environment? Where would I specify that? I only have gems specified in the Gemfile

Comment: You can have development and production areas to a Gemfile. Depending on your deployment method (I use capistrano) you can easily miss a bundle install (ie you have an updated Gem on your development that doesn't get updated on your production). 
I make sure all my capistrano scripts run bundle install for every deployment.
Just trying to think of ways that dev and production can differ if the source code is identical.

Comment: No different sections as far as I know.

Comment: Hmm, I'm fast running out of ideas I'm afraid. I'll dig about later on for you.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the error by installing RVM and upgrading to Ruby 1.9.3. There must be something in the 1.8.7 version that comes with OS X that causes these problems because I started getting them for other queries.

Earlier I was using 1.9.2 but had to downgrade because my hosting site still uses 1.8.7.

I appreciate all your help, they were really good ideas, thanks a lot.